# javascript/ajax login system

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I want to use script/ajax for my login system. So far I've been able to get back the array with all the errors and, if log in is successful set the $_SESSION['id']:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[type=button]").click(function () {  
var username = $('input[id=username]').val(); // get the username 
var password = $('input[id=password]').val(); // and the password
    if (username != '' || password !='') { // if not empty 

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "loginUser.php",
            data : "username="+username+"&password="+password,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
            var success = data['success'];
            if(success == 'false'){
            var error = data['message'];
            alert(error); // the array with all the errors
             }else{
       $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
       $('#mask').remove();  
    });// end fadeOut function()
setTimeout("location.href = 'home.php';",1500);
    }
  }
  });//end success function

  } else {
alert('Enter some text ! '); // just in case somebody to click witout writing anything :)
    }
    });//end click function
});//end ready function
  </script>
```

loginUser.php basically check all the function and then send back the data like this:

```
if (empty($_POST)===false){
$email = sanitize($_POST['username']);
$password = sanitize($_POST['password']);


if (empty($email) === true || empty ($password) === true){ 

    $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password';
} else if (mail_exists($email) === false){
    $errors[] = 'we can\'t find that username. have you registered?';
}else if (user_active($email) === false){
    $errors[] = 'you haven\'t activated your account!';
}else {
$login = login($email, $password);
if ($login === false){
    $errors[] = 'username/password combination is incorrect!';
}else {
//set user session 
$_SESSION['id'] = $login;

//redirect user to home
    echo json_encode(array("success"=>'true'
                ));
}

   }
echo json_encode(array("success"=>'false',
            "message"=>$errors,             
            ));
                          }
```

as I said, I get ALL the alert if password and username are not correct and I get the $_SESSION set if password and username are correct but the popup stays shown and I don't get redirect (but I can access because of the SESSION set). Is it correct to test if success is == true or == false???

*****EDIT: fixed, the problem was in the php file. look at my answer....

Comment: still trying, I really can't figure it out... any ideas?

Comment: Redirect on callback. Although if you redirect the user to another page after login, you might just perform the login upon redirection. No need for ajax

Comment: @mattia:What do you get in "data" for both cases(valid and invalid login)?

Comment: I wanted to give the errors (in case the login is unsuccessful) in a nice way and I thought ajax/javascript was the best way. do you see what I do wrong in my code?

Comment: @Irfan if login is not valid I get the message connected to the error (user not active, user not find, etc)... if login is valid I send (al least it's what I try to do) success=>'true'... at this point I would like to make a nice fadeOut of the login popup and redirect the user to home.php

Comment: @mattia:Did you try my answer?I am curious to know the problem.Please let me know when you have the answer.

Comment: @mattia:Is your JS if/else condition working fine?

Comment: @Irfan fixed...I will post the answer... the problem was on the php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed! the problem was in the if else logic in the php file:

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
      var username = $('input[id=username]').val(); // get the content of what user typed ( in textarea ) 
      var password = $('input[id=password]').val(); // get the content of what user typed ( in textarea ) 
                            $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "loginUser.php",
                            data : "username="+username+"&password="+password,
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                            var success = data['success'];
                            if(success == false){
        var error = data['message'];
                            alert(error); // just in case somebody to click on share witout writing anything :


                                }

                                if(success == true) {
   $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
   $('#mask').remove();  
                                });// end fadeOut function()
    setTimeout("location.href = 'home.php';",1000);                                 
                                                }
                                                    }

                        });//end ajax             
                 });//end click function
         });//end ready function
```

loginUser.php:

```
   <?php
    if (empty($_POST)===false){
$email = sanitize($_POST['username']);
$password = sanitize($_POST['password']);

if (empty($email) === true || empty ($password) === true){ 
            $result = false;
            $errors = 'You need to enter a username and password';
            echo json_encode(array("success"=>$result,
                                   "message"=>$errors,             
                                   ));
} else if (mail_exists($email) === false){
            $result = false;
            $errors= 'we can\'t find that username. have you registered?';
            echo json_encode(array("success"=>$result,
                                   "message"=>$errors,             
                             ));
}else if (user_active($email) === false){
            $result = false;
            $errors = 'you haven\'t activated your account!';
            echo json_encode(array("success"=>$result,
                            "message"=>$errors,             
                             ));
}else {
$login = login($email, $password);
if ($login === false){
            $result = false;
            $errors = 'username/password combination is incorrect!';
            echo json_encode(array("success"=>$result,
                            "message"=>$errors,             
                             ));
} else {
//set user session 
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
$result = true;
    echo json_encode(array("success"=>$result
                               ));

}
}
}
?>
```